# Moving average on the fly when calculation other values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been sitting and programming on an RSI calculator all day, and in previous questions I have also become aware that there is another and easier way to calculate RSI. but now I just want this to succeed, it is also a learning process ;-)
But right now, I have to calculate a moving average from Gain in my dataframe

```
def rsi_calculator(df):
    last_adj_close = float(df. loc[0, 'Adj Close'])
    gain = float(0)
    loss = float(0)
    for col, row in df.iterrows():
        change = float((col, row["Adj Close"])[1])-last_adj_close
        row['Change'] = change
        last_adj_close = float((col, row["Adj Close"])[1])
        if change > 0:
            gain = abs(change)
            loss = float(0)
        elif change < 0:
            loss = abs(change)
            gain = float(0)
        else:
            loss = float(0)
            gain = float(0)
        row['Gain'] = gain
        row['Loss'] = loss

        avg_gain = row['Gain'].rolling(windows=14).mean
        row['AVG Gain'] = avg_gain
```

I keep getting the error:

```
    avg_gain = row['Gain'].rolling(windows=14).mean
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rolling'
```

I have also tried different versions of this one here

```
avg_gain = (col, row["Adj Close"])[1].rolling(window=14).mean
```

But same error message, can anyone help?

Comment: When you're using iterrows, `row['Gain']` is the single value in the current row for the given column, in this case a single float number. `rolling()` is meant to be applied along an entire column or row at once, not a singular value

Comment: yes, I was almost aware of it myself, but I just have a hard time figuring out how to go back in the row with a windue based on my current row position

Comment: It simply isn;t something you do in a loop using `.rolling`. You could store the values and calculate it yourself as you would while iterating any other data structure (list, etc), or you use the built-in function outside the `iterrows` and just do `df['AVG Gain']=df['Gain'].rolling(windows=14).mean`